# Sine rule: Why doesn't it work in this scenario?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Why does:

$$\frac{4.5}{\sin40^\circ} \not= \frac{3+3}{\sin(180^\circ - 58^\circ)}$$

Am I using the rule wrong? Any incorrect assumptions?

Comment: You may be dealing with the ambiguous case of the law of sines. See here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#The_ambiguous_case

Comment: @noobProgrammer this isn't the ambiguous case, since all 3 angles are known.

Comment: I would say that you could try drawing this type of triangle, taking 40 degrees, 6 m and 4.5 m, but you would get around 58.99 degrees for the acute angle at P instead of 58 degrees. So, I think that a lot of the values in that drawing have been rounded off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application of the sine rule is correct. You'll find that your two numbers are in fact equal to two decimal. The problem comes from the lengths (or angles) being rounded. For example, the correct length of the side given length $6\,\text{m}$ should be $5.94\,\text{m}$ to two decimal places.

Comment: Seems a bit obvious now, thanks. :-)

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar No worries, glad I could help. What were you trying to work out?

Comment: The resultant moment about P: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352390/calculating-the-resultant-moment-about-a-point-p